# Need to show username in combo-box after successful log in in PHP

Tags: php, combobox

i want to show the username after successful login in a combobox.

```
<?php
$val = $_POST['applicant']?:'';

$sql = "SELECT username FROM `user` where password = '".$_SESSION['password']."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $selected = ($val == $row1['username'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '');
    echo '<option value ="' . $row1['username'] . '" '. $selected .'>' . $row1['username'] . '</option>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$val = "";
if(isset($_POST['applicant']))
{
  $val = $_POST['applicant'];
}

$sql = "SELECT username FROM `user` where password = '".$_SESSION['password']."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $selected = ($val == $row1['username']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value ="' . $row1['username'] . '" '. $selected .'>' . $row1['username'] . '</option>';
```

**UPDATE**

update for `still no result` comment

you can use trim you post value and check it in table `user` in column `username` mannualy that exists in database or not

```
 $val = "";
    if(isset($_POST['applicant']))
    {
      $val = trim($_POST['applicant']);
    }
echo $val;


}
```

Comment: i think issue is not clear. i have a table named "user" that has username and password column. i am loging using this two value. after successfully login i want to insert the username as applicant field in another table.